# OpenGL glulookat function

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat, glu

I want to be able to view a planet sphere centred 0,0,0 with 10 units radius, 360 degrees and up down by clicking my keyboard buttons. What parameters do I put inside the glulookat() function as?
I know the Center XYZ should be 000 but what should eye and up vector be?

```
void gluLookAt( GLdouble eyeX,
    GLdouble eyeY,
    GLdouble eyeZ,
    GLdouble centerX,
    GLdouble centerY,
    GLdouble centerZ,
    GLdouble upX,
    GLdouble upY,
    GLdouble upZ);
```

Comment: Which way is up?  Is it (0,0,1)?  If so, then use that for your "up" vector.  The "eye" vector is the location of *you* the viewer (your eye).

Comment: can you figure out how to calculate the camera position you want?

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use `lookAt` for this!](https://stannum.io/blog/0UaG8R) The amount of trigonometry involved in calculating the eye vector is equivalent to building the view matrix from scratch.

Instead, maintain your camera pitch and yaw, and apply those by a series of translations and rotations:

```
glTranslatef(0, 0, -radius);
glRotatef(-pitch, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(-yaw, 0, 0, 1); // assumes Z is up
```